# magento observer

Tags: event-observer

hei everyone, i have module which use observer event **sales_model_service_quote_submit_after** , its work well so far

But, when i create other module with same observer event it not work, magento just fire observer of my first module. My observer of my second module its not fire

its my first config of observer :

```
 <events>
      <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <observers>
          <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Sprint_Migs_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>saveSiteID</method>
          </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        </observers>
      </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
</events>
```

its my second config of observer :

```
 <events>
      <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <observers>
          <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Sprint_BcaKlikPay_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>saveData</method>
          </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        </observers>
      </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
    </events>
```

Its my observer of my first module

```
<?php
```

class Sprint_Migs_Model_Observer{

```
public function saveSiteID($observer){
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
    if(isset($post['payment']['method'])){
        if ($post['payment']['method'] == "migs"){
            $merchantTransactionID  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
            $siteId                 = $post['payment']['site_id'];
            $transactionType        = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/migs/transactionType');
            $currency               = 'IDR';
            $amount                 = Mage::helper('migs')->getTotalPrice();

            $data       = array("merchantTransactionID" => $merchantTransactionID,"siteId" => $siteId,"transactionType" => $transactionType,"currency" => $currency,"amount" => $amount); 
            Mage::helper('migs')->insertMigsData($data);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Its my observer of my second module that not working :

```
<?php
```

class Sprint_BcaKlikPay_Model_Observer{

```
public function saveData($observer){
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
    if(isset($post['payment']['method'])){
        if ($post['payment']['method'] == "bcaklikpay"){
            $transactionNo  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
            $tenor          = $post['payment']['bca_tenor'];
            $payType        = Mage::helper('bcaklikpay')->getPayType($tenor);   

            $data       = array("transactionNo" => $transactionNo,"payType" => $payType,"tenor" => $tenor); 
            Mage::helper('bcaklikpay')->insertData($data);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your observer definition:

```
<events>
  <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>      <--- event name
    <observers>
      <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>  <--- unique identifier for the OBSERVER
```

The observer identifier can be anything, as long as it is unique. As soon as you use the same identifier twice for one event, it overrides the previous observer. Usually you would use your module name as identifier to avoid conflicts with other modules.